# I accidentally removed python, now apt-get is completely broken

Tags: debian, python, apt

So I was having problems installing certbot/letsencrypt becaus eof a python Error. So i decided to remove python

```
apt-get remove --purge python
```

But I cannot `apt-get install python` because It complains about python not being installed to install it.

Anyway I've heard I can try to install all the python packages manually via dpkg, How do I do this.

Should I download packages sepearteley or can it be done with dpkg?
And If so, How do I do this?

---

Edit:

[image]

(Im using python2.7) So its obviusly not installed for python2.7? only 3
Thanks.

Comment: "_with great power comes great responsibility_"...

Comment: what version of Debian are you on? depending on how many other critical system packages you've also removed... this could either be straightforward to fix, or not worth the hassle (easier to reinstall)

Comment: @Attie yes I should have done my research first..

Comment: @Attie I am using Stretch (Raspberry pi)

Comment: On my current OS install everything has been trouble installing, nodejs didnt work , mariadb didnt work..... Everything has been trouble im wondering If I just format and start again. It would only take a few seconds If everything went to plan, this install took 5 hours..

Comment: @Attie ok I think Ive fixed some python, not sure how. ButI'm just getting one error. ImportError: no module named site

Comment: Im guessing then somethin (site.py most liekly) is missing?

Comment: @Attie Ive edited in a screenshot which might be helpful.

Comment: I've just done `apt-get remove --purge python` followed by `apt-get install python` with no problems on a fresh image... what else did you do? =)

Comment: @Attie I'm pretty sure thats all I did but after I had alot of unmet dependencies and god know I cant remember, Im gonna try an apt-get install python now.

Comment: @Attie I cant purge python now.... Im getting PYTHONHOME error and what not. I think I will reinstall when I have time...

Comment: Sounds like a good plan

Comment: The `apt` intself does not depend on Python (it's written in C++). Supposedly you have another package (which depends on Python) in a botched state, and when `apt` tries to configure it, it fails. I'd try running `apt-get install python` with `--fix-broken` and `--ignore-missing` command-line options for a start.